# How to make an element's border flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to flash or blink the border of a particular div when the user mouse over an element and stop flashing when mouse out. I have several elements that can user user mouseover. I need to flash the div every time when the user mouse over.

I have tried this.

```
#DivToolTip{ border: 3px solid white; }
#DivToolTip.red-border { border: 3px solid red; }

var flashInterval;

flashInterval = setInterval(function() { // called at mouseover
    $('#DivToolTip').toggleClass('red-border');
}, 1000);


window.clearInterval(flashInterval); // called at mouseout
```

but it not blinking properly, on the very first time it blinks properly after 1 sec when I mouseover on another element it blinks rapidly or more fast.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please setup a jsfiddle where we can see the problem and help you to solve it. You're not including enough here for us to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var flashInterval;

$('#DivToolTip').hover(
    function () {
    flashInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#DivToolTip').toggleClass('red-border');
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(flashInterval);
    $('#DivToolTip').removeClass('red-border');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jUxTw/)

**UPDATE**

If you want to hover on an element and another one flashes then you should change your jQuery selectors based on the ids of your elements you want to perfom each action.

See updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jUxTw/2/)

Comment: A good answer, but I would encourage OP to use CSS animations for something like this instead. The above code can be used as backup using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-cssanimations-shiv-cssclasses) when CSS animations aren't available.

Comment: I want to flash only particular div and not the element I am hovering on.

Answer (score 42):

### [You can do this in pure CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/y8kNx/836/)

Thereby keeping your separation of concerns by ***keeping CSS for your styling***

HTML

```
<div class='borderBlink'>Border flash on hover</div>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes borderBlink {    
    from, to {    
        border-color: transparent    
    }    
    50% {    
        border-color: black    
    }    
}    
@keyframes borderBlink {    
    from, to {    
        border-color: transparent    
    }    
    50% {    
        border-color: black    
    }    
}    
.borderBlink{    
    border:1px solid black;
    /* add 'border-color: transparent' if you wish no border to show initially */  
}
.borderBlink:hover {    
    -webkit-animation: borderBlink 1s step-end infinite;    
    animation: borderBlink 1s step-end infinite;    
}
```

Comment: [More about CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: +1 Pure CSS solution. Is there a way i can achieve the same functionallity but the element in the no hover state with no border?

Comment: FYI: there are [alternative animations](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp) instead of `step-end`. Also, replace `infinite` with a number if you only need it to blink a couple of times. Great code, thanks @SW4

Comment: i personally prefer `ease-in-out` over `step-end` because it gradually animates it. though, using `rgba()` color definition may be required depending on the browser to make that happen

Answer (score 5):

No need to use jQuery for this, you can do it fairly simply with CSS [animations and keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations):

First, set up your keyframe to set the border to red 50% of the time:

```
@keyframes blink { 
   50% { border-color: #ff0000; } 
}
```

Then set up the div (you can use an ID, class, or just any element) to use the animation:

```
.class:hover {
    animation: blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
}
```

And set up a transparent border to start:

```
.class {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udcaV/)

Comment: nb: In order for a keyframe list to be valid, it must include rules for at least the times 0% (or from) and 100% (or to). src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
[class*="fI_"]{
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.fI_bg *:not(.btn),.fI_bo *:not(.btn){color:#fff}
.fI_bg{
    animation-name:fI_bg;
}
.fI_bo{
    animation-name:fI_bo;
}
@keyframes fI_bg{
0%{background-color:#0D78BD;}25%{background-color:#1C3B50;}50%{background-color:#0D78BD;}75%{background-color:#1C3B50;}100%{background-color:#0D78BD;}
}
@keyframes fI_bo{
0%{border-color:#0D78BD;}25%{border-color:#1C3B50;}50%{border-color:#0D78BD;}75%{border-color:#1C3B50;}100%{border-color:#0D78BD;}
}
```

jQuery Alternative :

```
$.fn.fI=function(e){//Flash Item
    if(!e){e={}}
    if(this){e.e=this}
    switch(e.f){
        case 0:
        break;
        default:
            switch(e.css){
                case 0:
                    e.d='background-color'
                break;
                case undefined:
                    e.d='border-color'
                break;
                default:
                    e.d=e.css
                break;
            }
            if(!e.c1){e.c1='#1D89CF'}
            if(!e.c2){e.c2='#1aae88'}
            if(!e.p){e.p=200}
            e.e.css(e.d,e.c1)
            setTimeout(function(){
                e.e.css(e.d,e.c2)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    e.e.css(e.d,e.c1)
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        e.e.css(e.d,e.c2)
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            e.e.css(e.d,'')
                        },e.p)
                    },e.p)
                },e.p)
            },e.p)
        break;
    }
    return this
}
```

**Use like this:**

does border if you leave css undefined

```
$('#elementid').fI()
```

does if you do 0 it will do background-color, and anything else will be the become the property. so you can do font color or box-shadow like this:

```
$('#elementid').fI({css:'color'})
$('#elementid').fI({css:'box-shadow',c1:'0 0 10px #333',c2:'0 0 5px #F00'})
```

does background

```
$('#elementid').fI({css:0})
```

use different colors and set interval in miliseconds

```
$('#elementid').fI({c1:'#fff',c2:'#F00',p:1000})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have plain Javascript version

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flash;

function flashBorder(elmId, stopFlash)
{
    var elm = document.getElementById(elmId);  
    if(stopFlash == "true")
    {
        elm.style.border = "";
        clearInterval(flash);
    }
    else
    {
        var borderPattern = false;
        flash = setInterval(setBorder,300);

        function setBorder()
        {
            if(borderPattern)
            {
                borderPattern = false;
                elm.style.border = "solid white";
                elm.style.borderWidth = "3px";
            }
            else
            {
                borderPattern = true;
                elm.style.border = "solid blue";
                elm.style.borderWidth = "3px";
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div id="FLASH_ME" onmouseenter="flashBorder('FLASH_ME', 'false')" onmouseleave="flashBorder('FLASH_ME', 'true')">Hello Friends!</div>
```